# Problem with state actualization in redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm having some (probably stupid) problem with updating state in toolkit.

I'm doing my first major project after finishing the React course and I ran into a problem with updating the state in the **markAsKnown** function, I want it to get the updated state immediately after the first click **state.maxIndex = state.technologyArray.length**, and it happens after the second.

You can see on the screenshot that after the first click on the **markAsKnown call** nothing changes, only on the second click is there an update, but this blows everything up because one that on the page I want to display the length of the technologyArray which informs about the remaining questions, and two that it affects the index draw which by doing so can be longer than the length of the array.

This is my Slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import QuestionsData from '@/data/QuestionsData';

const initialState = {
maxIndex: 10, // chwilowo
index: 0,
questions: QuestionsData,
technology: 'JavaScript',
technologyArray: [],
};

const questionSlice = createSlice({
name: 'question',
initialState,

reducers: {
getRandomIndex: (state) => {
  state.index = Math.floor(Math.random() * state.maxIndex);
},

getTechnologyArray: (state, action) => {
  state.technologyArray = state.questions.filter(
    (tech) => action.payload === tech.tech && tech.known === false
  );
  state.maxIndex = state.technologyArray.length;
  state.technology = action.payload;
  state.index = 0;
},

markAsKnown: (state) => {
  state.technologyArray = state.questions.filter(
    (tech) => state.technology === tech.tech && tech.known === false
  );
  state.maxIndex = state.technologyArray.length;
  state.technologyArray[state.index].known = true;
  if (state.maxIndex === 0) console.log('Koniec pytań');
},

resetCategory: (state) => {
  state.questions = QuestionsData;
},
},
});

export const {
markAsKnown,
getRandomIndex,
index,
getTechnologyArray,
technologyArray,
} = questionSlice.actions;

export default questionSlice.reducer;
```

`

And here i call it:

```
import { BsCheckCircle, BsXCircle } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const KnownUnknownButtons = ({ markAsKnown, getRandomIndex }) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

return (
<div className="max-w-7xl w-full flex flex-col justify-between items-center mx-auto p-5 ">
  <div className="flex mt-10 flex justify-around w-full sm:w-4/5 md:w-3/5 lg:w-1/2 ">
    <button className=" flex justify-center">
      <BsXCircle
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(getRandomIndex());
        }}
        className="h-14 w-14 hover:text-red-500 transition-all hover:scale-105 active:scale-95"
      />
    </button>
    <button className=" flex justify-center">
      <BsCheckCircle
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(getRandomIndex());
          dispatch(markAsKnown());
        }}
        className="h-14 w-14 hover:text-teal-500 transition-all hover:scale-105 active:scale-95"
      />
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
);
};
export default KnownUnknownButtons;
```

`

I've tried dropping states into variables and assigning them to states, reordering the code, I've even tried fixing it with gpt chat, but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue could be related to updating your Redux state after a button click. Consider using a functional update approach when modifying technologyArray and maxIndex in your markAsKnown reducer. This might help ensure immediate state updates after the first click.

For example:

```
markAsKnown: (state) => {
  const newTechArray = 
  state.technologyArray.map((tech, idx) => 
  {
    return (idx === state.index) ? { 
    ...tech, known: true } : tech;
   });
  state.technologyArray = newTechArray;
  state.maxIndex = 
  newTechArray.filter(tech => 
  !tech.known).length;
  if (state.maxIndex === 0) 
  console.log('End of questions');
 },
```

Comment: Hallelujah! Your code was close to result what i wanted to have.
I mixed it together and now it's work fine.
I'll need to refactor it but it's working.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Hello there! I'm glad I could assist you in achieving the desired outcome. If my answer has been helpful and resolved your issue, please consider giving it a thumbs-up. Your positive feedback would be greatly appreciated. If you have any further questions or need more assistance, feel free to ask. Thank you